# how to loop add message into string by fetch from object?

Tags: javascript

I make my own dictionary, I keep all word in an object. I use by put some content into content variable
and loop for find the word if which word found, should add message. 
How I have to do it?

---

- Can I have result like this

Boom is an American company. It wants to make a new plane. The plan is to have a plane in 2023 The plane will(to happen in the future) be supersonic. It will(to happen in the future) fly from London to New York in three hours. The flight(a journey in an aircraft) ticket will(to happen in the future) not be extremely expensive. It will(to happen in the future) cost as much as a standard business class ticket.

---

mycode

```
let content = "Boom is an American company. It wants to make a new plane. The plan is to have a plane in 2023 The plane will be supersonic. It will fly from London to New York in three hours. The flight ticket will not be extremely expensive. It will cost as much as a standard business class ticket.";


var myDictionary = 
{
   will: "to happen in the future",
   flight: "a journey in an aircraft",
   cost: "the amount of money needed to buy",
   particular: "or this and not any other"
}


for(let i in myDictionary) {//each word


    for(i=0;/**/)//this word found, such as "will" have to 4 rounds  
    {
       /*loop for find, how many position in this word. 
       if this word has 2 positions that first loop add my transalate message after the fist position of word and round 2, if more it's have to keep loop until no found this position and out to main loop for find next word 
       add in the second position.
       */  
        generate(i);
    }  

}  


function generate(word)
{

   let find_position = content.indexOf(word);
      console.log(find_position);
   let length_of_word = word.length;
   let find_position_after_word = find_position + length_of_word;
   let transalate_word = getProperty(word);
   let output = content.slice(0, find_position_after_word), transalate_word, content.slice(find_position_after_word)].join('');
}

function getProperty(word_for_transalate)
{
   return myDictionary[word_for_transalate];
}
```

Comment: what's the point of `generate` ... it returns nothing, and effectively does nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var output = Object.keys(myDictionary).reduce( function(a,b,i){
   if (i == 1)
   {
       a = content.replace( new RegExp( a, "gi" ), a + "(" + myDictionary[ a ] + ")" ); 
   }
   a = a.replace( new RegExp( b, "gi" ), b + "(" + myDictionary[ b ] + ")" ); 
   return a;
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var content = "Boom is an American company. It wants to make a new plane. The plan is to have a plane in 2023 The plane will be supersonic. It will fly from London to New York in three hours. The flight ticket will not be extremely expensive. It will cost as much as a standard business class ticket.";

var myDictionary = {
  will: "to happen in the future",
  flight: "a journey in an aircraft",
  cost: "the amount of money needed to buy",
  particular: "or this and not any other"
};

var output = Object.keys(myDictionary).reduce(function(a, b, i) {
  if (i == 1) {
    a = content.replace(new RegExp(a, "gi"), a + "(" + myDictionary[a] + ")");
  }
  a = a.replace(new RegExp(b, "gi"), b + "(" + myDictionary[b] + ")");
  return a;
});

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Thank you, It's so simple that who know it.

Answer (score 0):

Find position of string within your string and append the value of key-value pair next to it within braces.

```js
var a = "Boom is an American company. It wants to make a new plane.";

var obj = {
"wants" : "2",
"is": "one"
}

for(var key in obj) {
let position = a.indexOf(key) + key.length + 1;
a = [a.slice(0, position), '('+obj[key]+')', a.slice(position)].join('');
}

console.log(a)
```